# Using RxNetty as proxy server without blocking the client

Tags: rx-java, rx-netty

I have an RxNetty server which is transforming the requests and sending it via HTTP to another service.
I did not find a way to perform a non-blocking request with the HttpClient.
I want to fail the request on timeout.
The only way I found to be working is:

```
client.submit(request)
    .flatMap(response -> response.getContent().
        map(byteBuf -> byteBuf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())))
    .toBlocking().toFuture().get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Did you try `submit(request).timeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)...`?

Comment: can you provide an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

submit(request).timeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)